# Paper about "where is the knee of an exponentional function?"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, exponential-function

It is a common mistake to name some point of an exponential function "knee".

Some years ago I found a nice paper which collected some examples and some extra anecdotes about this. I do not remember, if it was published in a physics or mathematics journal.

Do you know a paper (perhaps this specific paper) about the "knee" mistake?

Some links about the "knee":

- [Is there a name for the point of a exponential curve where the y axis significantly increases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690677/is-there-a-name-for-the-point-of-a-exponential-curve-where-the-y-axis-significan)
- http://www.abarry.org/knee.htm